# Secondary connection to a server gives me a error

Tags: android, connection, android-asynctask

In an recent [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710531/how-to-access-sqlite-database-from-ui-thread-if-im-inserting-data-in-asynctask), I commented that I have a library class called `HttpPostAux.java`.

It works when I call it from Main.java (main activity) to validate user login (here I use an `AsyncTask` thread to connect to server). But when I use it to replace old password in case user has forgotten it (here I use another `AsyncTask` thread to connect to server), it gives me an error:

An error occurred while executing `doInBackground()` ... Caused by: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

But when I look for that null, surprise: I didn't find it! And in my humble opinion, this error shouldn't exist because `HttpPostAux` isn't attached to any activity in particular.

Can anybody help me here? Which is the correct way to use different `AsyncTask` threads in different activities? I would publish some code, but I'm out of time right now...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using httpurlconnection this is not good in lower api's 
see this link http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011_09_01_archive.html

Comment: Where do you get the idea he is using HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: because i had the same problem and HttpUrlConnection when you get for example image for more than time the first image will load the second will crash